# Apply quaternion is not a function

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need some light on this question I'm trying to set vertices of a geometry using a quaternion and

```
geometry.attributes.position.array[x].applyQuaternion(quaternion)
```

is not working as expected
I know this implementation as changed in the passed and I suspect that the problem is that

```
geometry.vertices[x]
```

is not available anymore

some one on this ?

Comment: I might be wrong here, but isnt everything in the buffer geometries in THREE.js just arrays and numbers? They're not classes like Vector3 (because it would be inefficient to do so). I think regular geometries were removed from threeJS, and you have a pull them for the buffers, edit them and place them back now?

Comment: Since r125, there is no `Geometry` class in the core.

Comment: About the removal of `THREE.Geometry`: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-geometry-will-be-removed-from-core-with-r125/22401

Answer (score 1):

The method `.applyQuaternion()` is [only available in `Vector3()`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=vector#api/en/math/Vector3.applyQuaternion), not in a simple number. You cannot perform `7.applyQuaternion()` with a number. In this context, it doesn't make sense to apply a 3D rotation to a 1-dimensional value.

First, make sure you create a Vector3 with the XYZ coordinates of the vertex you're trying to manipulate by using [the BufferAttribute.get... method](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=vector#api/en/core/BufferAttribute.getX):

```js
// Create quaternion
const quat = new THREE.Quaternion();
quat.setFromAxisAngle( /* ... */ );

// Position attribute
const posAttrib = geometry.getAttribute('position');

// Let's get the XYZ components of the 7th vertex in the geometry
const twistVec = new THREE.Vector3(
    posAttrib.getX(7),
    posAttrib.getY(7),
    posAttrib.getZ(7)
);

// Now that you've created a Vec3, you CAN apply a quaternion
twistVec.applyQuaternion(quat);
```